# What happend to the airframe of the Aloha Airlines Flight 243?

Tags: boeing-737, accident-investigation

What happened to the airframe of Aloha Airlines Flight 243, after the explosive decompression? 
I know that the structures were studied for a while after the aircraft safely landed in  Kahului Airport, but what happened after that?

Comment: [It was written off](http://libraryonline.erau.edu/online-full-text/ntsb/aircraft-accident-reports/AAR89-03.pdf) and dismantled.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Exchange Aviation.

Comment: Thank you. That was my first question, I had always wondered what happened to the airframe, and now I know!

Comment: Accident report of [Aloha 243](http://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/maintenance_hf/library/documents/media/human_factors_maintenance/aircraft_accident_report--aloha_airlines.flight_243.boeing_737-200.n73711.near_maui.hawaii.april_28.1988.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Planespotters](https://m.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/737/20209/N73711-Aloha-Airlines), it appears that the airframe in question was destroyed in August 1988.

Comment: The link is broken.